# .Net (C#) Enum rewritten to java

Tags: c#, java, .net

I have an Enum in .Net. How can I rewrite this Enum in java?

Here is the Enum:

```
public enum AdCategoryType : short
{
    ForSale = 1,
    ForBuy = 2,
    ForRent = 8,
    WantingForRent = 16,
    WorkIsWanted = 32, 
    WorkIsGiven = 64
}
```

Comment: This is actually a flags-style enum and should probably have a "[Flags]" attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you the enum:

```
public enum AdCategoryType {

    ForSale(1),

    ForBuy(2),

    ForRent(4),

    WantingForRent(8),

    WorkIsWanted(16),

    WorkIsGiven(32);

    private final int value;

    AdCategoryType(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get Java syntax errors when I do this, "<identifier> expected" plus several more. Moving the "private final int value;" statement down, like in the other two answers, fixes this. Using Java 1.7 - maybe they've changed the syntax?

Comment: No, just didn't compile it three years ago when I first posted this.  I added a type for value in the ctor and moved the declaration down.  It works now.

Comment: Wow, so you got your answer accepted and got two plus votes despite your answer not working! Never happens for me ...  :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
public enum AdCategoryType {
    ForSale/*           */ (1 << 0), //
    ForBuy/*            */ (1 << 1), //
    ForRent/*           */ (1 << 2), //
    WantingForRent/*    */ (1 << 3), //
    WorkIsWanted/*      */ (1 << 4), //
    WorkIsGiven/*       */ (1 << 5);
    private final int value;

    private AdCategoryType(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
};
```

To get the value of `ForBuy` use `AdCategoryType.ForBuy.getValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Foo
{
   Bar(1),
   Baz(45);

   private short myValue;

   private short value()
   {
     return myValue;
   }

   public Foo(short val)
   {
      myValue = val;
   }
```

}